# Understanding how the quartic Higgs coupling turns negative at high energies

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, stability, unitarity

1. How is the conclusion that *the Higgs quartic coupling becomes negative at high energies ($\sim 10^{10}$) GeV* inferred? I'm looking for a reference that has the necessary idea and calculations to understand this.
2. What does this instability of Higgs potential at such energies imply at a conceptual level?

Comment: For starters, where did you read that the quartic Higgs coupling turns negative at high energies? where did you get this idea from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed a lot in light of the Higgs mass measurement in 2012, since the mass constrains the low-renormalization scale, $\mu \sim M_W $, the value of the Higgs quartic, $\lambda (\mu \sim M_W) $.

When the quartic is run from the low-scale upwards with RGEs, the negative Yukawa contributions eventually overpower the positive gauge ones in the beta-functions. This drives the coupling negative. This is treated in detail in e.g. [1205.6497](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6497).

At a conceptual level, it means the Higgs potential has a second deeper minimum at a large field value because
$$
V (h) \simeq \lambda(\mu = h) h^4
$$
The true minimum is separated from our local minima by a potential barrier. In principle, we could undergo a disastrous phase transition and tunnel to the true minima. The tunneling probability though is believed to be negligible.

There are many subtleties and technical points overlooked in my brief description.

Comment: @SRS No, I did not. Try the ref in my answer and see eq. 51